# Rails 5: Refactoring - One to Many Relationship (Tests and Views)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-5

Somewhat new to rails and trying to figure out some answers to questions I've been having with no real luck using the Rails Documentation or on the rails guides, or rails tutorials.

My goal is to embrace how rails handles things and try to make it easy for other developers to step into the project later.

**Question 1: Refactoring Question**

Rails practice in refactoring.  I'm not sure if this should go in the model or the controller and really just want to know what items should go in the controller versus what should go in the model.

First Iteration :

```
<% @departments.each do |department| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= department.name %></td>
        <td><%= department.description %></td>
        <td>
          <%= library = Library.find_by(id: department.library_id).name %>
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', department %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_department_path(department) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', department, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

This seemed wrong to me and seemed like that should be taken out of that part as backend logic.

Second Iteration:

Model

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library

  def get_library_name(lib_id)
    library = Library.find_by(id: lib_id)
    return library.name
  end
end
```

View

```
<% @departments.each do |department| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= department.name %></td>
        <td><%= department.description %></td>
        <td>
          <%= department.get_library_name(department.library_id) %>
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', department %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_department_path(department) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', department, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

This feels more correct, but not all the way there, so I'm not really sure how I can change it to be more correct, especially since the index view which lists out the records is very similar.

How should I refactor this?

**Question 2: My Test Won't Pass**

Either way, my test isn't passing.  I'm guessing it is the way I'm using my one to many relationships.

```
  test "should get index" do
    get departments_url
    assert_response :success
  end
```

error:

```
DepartmentsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    app/models/department.rb:6:in `get_library_name'
    app/views/admin/departments/index.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_admin_departments_index_html_erb__1894713831414342893_57284960'
    app/views/admin/departments/index.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_admin_departments_index_html_erb__1894713831414342893_57284960'
    test/controllers/departments_controller_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:DepartmentsControllerTest>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

You can easily access the query for the associated library using the association method.

Whenever you added `belong_to :library` to `Department`, you're really just creating a method called `library` on instances of `Department` that calls the appropriate query for you.

The same happens for the `has_many`, `has_one` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations, expect the reverse happens.

Instead of looking for `Library.find_by(id: department.library_id)` it does the opposite, `Department.find_by(library_id: department.library_id)`.

All these can be easily accessed through the associative methods.

```
department = Department.first
library = department.library
```

To get back to the question, personally, I like exposing the largest dataset to my views and narrowing down from there.

I would only send a `@department`, to the view and not bother creating a method to show the name or `delegate` the name from library to department (with prefix) to get a `library_name` method.

```
<% @departments.each do |department| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= department.name %></td>
    <td><%= department.description %></td>
    <td><%= department.library.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', department %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_department_path(department) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', department, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

**Question 2:**

Unfortunately, I don't have much of an answer. The problem is that there is little information to work with, but also now we're involving many methods that could be sending and the nil can domino it's way all the way to your model method.

I strongly suspect one of your departments did not have a `library_id`, which is crashing your loop as it depends on each department having a library.

## EDIT

**Question 3:**

To get the inverse relationship, you simply do `department.libraries`.

In the situation you described, you had a collection of departments, which is different from a single department instance.

Comment: this worked perfectly and a great explanation.  I'm going to mark your answer correct, but could you explain the inverse, if I wanted to get all departments to be listed in my library view? When inspect the @libraries item which is pointing to Library.all I don't see any departments.

Comment: @DavidJ.Davis Updated my answer